# Find the covariance of a brownian motion.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, covariance

Given a standard Brownian motion $\{W_t\}_{t\geq0}$, find the value of $\operatorname{Cov}\left(W_t,W_s\right)$.

Is there a way to simplify $$\operatorname{Cov}\left(W_t,W_s\right)?$$

Comment: How do you know that the latter term is $0$? It is because you know that each $w_t$ has a mean $0$ and $(w_t, w_s)$ are independent when $t \neq s$? So for the term here, the remaining work is to find out when the index coincide so that you may have a non-zero result (actually only $2$ special cases to consider and only the trivial case is non-zero)

Comment: Becasuse ${w_t}\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the properties and Brownian motion and the linearity of the Covariance, we easily get for $t \geq s$:

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Cov}\bigl(W_s, W_t\bigr) &= \operatorname{Cov}\bigl(W_s, W_t - W_s + W_s\bigr) =\operatorname{Cov}\bigl(W_s, W_t-W_s\bigr) + \operatorname{Cov}\bigl(W_s, W_s\bigr)  \\
 &= 0 + Var(W_s) = s.
\end{align}

Similarly if $s \geq t$ you get
$$
\operatorname{Cov}\bigl(W_s, W_t\bigr) = t.
$$

So in general, we have that 
$$
\operatorname{Cov}\bigl(W_s, W_t\bigr) = \min\{s,t\}.
$$